# argument after * must be an iterable, not int

Tags: function, python-3.6

I have a small script that takes in a list and a value that represents what size sublists to break the list into:

```
def chunk(alist, n):
    i = 0
    j = n
    while j < (len(alist) + 2):
        sub = alist[i:j]
        i += n
        j += n
        print(sub)

chunk([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2)
```

This works.  I get [1, 2] [3, 4] [5]

But if I try to return sub from the function and print it in a loop it fails with: argument after * must be an iterable, not int

```
def chunks(alist, n):
    i = 0
    j = n
    while j < (len(alist) + 2):
        sub = alist[i:j]
        i += n
        j += n
        return sub

for chunk in chunks([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2):
    print(*chunk)
```

sub is an iterable (a list).  Not sure what I am doing wrong.

*NOTE* cannot use itertools or any other add ons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `sub` variable holds only a slice of the list. It should instead be appended to a list of lists as the returning value of the `chunks` function:

```
def chunks(alist, n):
    i = 0
    j = n
    output = []
    while j < (len(alist) + 2):
        output.append(alist[i:j])
        i += n
        j += n
    return output

for chunk in chunks([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2):
    print(*chunk)
```

This outputs:

```
1 2
3 4
5
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.